# Prove $f$ has a zero given $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty, \lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = - \infty$

Tags: limits, analysis, continuity, proof-writing

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty, \lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = - \infty$$

How can one show that there exists a zero of this function?
And can $f$ have more than one zeros?

I thought of $x^3$ which approaches $\infty$ for $x \to \infty$ and $- \infty$ for $x \to - \infty$.

But I don't know how one can prove that $f$ has a zero.

Comment: It is a corollary of the [Intermediate value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)

Comment: Of course, $f$ can have any odd number of finite zeros. For example try constructing a polynomial

Comment: if you go from $\infty$ to $-\infty$ then ypu will cross the real axis i.e X axis and that point where it cut the X axis is your zero

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Why odd? $f$ can have any number of zeros, odd or even (but at least one, of course).

Comment: @zipirovich Yes, sorry, that is a mistake: If you count "touches" of the line $y=0$ as two zeros (for example the polynomial $x^2$ has such a touch), then I think that $f$ can only have odd zeros

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch: Yes, for polynomials it is so. But since $f$ is only presumed to be continuous, not necessarily differentiable -- let alone analytic, the concept of multiplicity doesn't make sense. For example, imagine a continuous zigzagging (i.e. piece-wise linear) function like $f(x)=x$ for $x\le0$, $f(x)=-x$ for $0<x\le1$, $f(x)=x-2$ for $x>1$. It has two roots, and I don't think there's any conceptually solid way to say that at $x=0$ it has "two zeros".

Comment: @zipirovich My original comment a bit more explicitly: By touching the zero line at $x_0$ I mean that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ such that $f(x)\le 0$ or $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment mentions, the solutions is quick if you are willing to use the intermediate value theorem.

To set it up, you need to show that $f$ takes on a negative and a positive value. For example, if $f(x_1) < 0$, $f(x_2) > 0$ and $x_1 < x_2$, then $f$ restricted to the interval $[x_1, x_2]$ has a zero by the intermediate value theorem.

How to find $x_1$ and $x_2$? Use the definition of the limit. $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ means for any $M_1$, there is $x'$ such that $f(x) > M_1$ for all $x > x'$. Similarly, $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ means for any $M_2$, there is $x'$ such that $f(x) < M_2$ for all $x < x'$. How would you choose $M_1$ and $M_2$?

The comments mention that in the case where $f$ is a polynomial, there are always an odd number of zeros counting multiplicity. In general, however, $f$ can obtain any number of zeros.

Comment: Pbn990.Nice answer.

Comment: I would choose $M_1>0$ and $M_2<0$, is that correct?